# PHP file created with fopen disappears

Tags: php, fopen

In my script I use fopen to create a txt file. When executing the script I can see the txt file being created on the ftp but when I refresh the ftp contents the file is gone? Is this normal behaviour or am I not using the fopen command correctly?

I am using it like this:

```
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you write via `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Are you using `fclose` as well, after you are done writing your data to the file …?

Comment: i am not using fclose, do I need to?

Comment: Even when using fclose the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Running just the PHP line given in the question the file stays on the server for me, even if nothing is written to it. Is there more code after this line that we should see?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to continuously write to this file (i.e. append more contents to it, since it is an error log), try using this:

```
$errorMessage = 'Test writing to errorlog.txt';
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', $errorMessage, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: indeed, it's meant to be an errorlog that gets filled every hour.
I am calling it from CURLOPT_STDERR    =>    $fp 
How should I implement your example in this?